# Global Array variable is not being populated from method in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following code in

```
var markers=[];
function updateMap(data){
    console.log(markers);
    if(markers.length>0)
        {
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            map.removeLayer(markers[i]);
        }
        }
    //location.reload();
    map.removeLayer(markers);
    var lat,lon;
    var road;
    var detector;
    //var svg=d3.select("#map").append("svg");
    //markers=[];
    //var count=0;
    map.dragging.enable();
    data.forEach(function(d)
            {
    //  count++;
        lat=d.lat;
        lon=d.lon;
        road=d.road;
        detector=d.detector;
        markers.push((new L.circle([lat, lon], 200, {
            color: 'yellow',
            fillColor: '#f0f',
            fillOpacity: 0.5
        })).bindPopup("Road Name:"+road+"<br>Detector ID: "+detector))

            });
    //console.log("Total Detectors= "+count);
    //console.log(markers);
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        map.addLayer(markers[i]);
    }
    map.setView([lat, lon],13);
    map.dragging.enable();
}
console.log(markers);
```

I am expecting to have values in the last console.log(markers) statement. But i am getting []. Why is this happening? Is the global variable not populated inside the method?

Comment: You never called the method.

Comment: I called the method from another function in another place

Comment: probably calling it inside an ajax response handler and ajax is asynchronous so you are attempting to consume the data before it has been returned from server

Comment: If you called the method from another place, then that other place is relevant.

Comment: If you make an envelope and your friend will fill it, the envelope will be empty if you look inside before your friend has had the chance to put something inside it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second call to the console is being run before the function updateMap is called. Place your second console.log() directly after you call updateMap.

Comment: I have called the second method from another place before going to the line outside the method

Comment: Even the first console.log(markers) also shows [] when i call the method second time from the change of value of combobox

Comment: I am still think that the second call is happing prior to the function being called.